# Route for custom Devise mapping

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7

i have defined:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users, controllers: {
    registrations: 'users/registrations'
  }
  root 'dashboard#index'
  
end
```

and i have customized the view as well as controller content.

When i submit my form from edit view, i cannot submit using :

`user_registration_path(current_user)`

but i can submit using

`registration_path(current_user)` .

However look at my `rails routes`

```
                            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)                                                                          devise/sessions#create
                    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)                                                                         devise/sessions#destroy
                       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)                                                                     devise/passwords#new
                      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)                                                                    devise/passwords#edit
                           user_password PATCH  /users/password(.:format)                                                                         devise/passwords#update
                                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)                                                                         devise/passwords#update
                                         POST   /users/password(.:format)                                                                         devise/passwords#create
                cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)                                                                           users/registrations#cancel
                   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)                                                                          users/registrations#new
                  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)                                                                             users/registrations#edit
                       user_registration PATCH  /users(.:format)                                                                                  users/registrations#update
                                         PUT    /users(.:format)                                                                                  users/registrations#update
                                         DELETE /users(.:format)                                                                                  users/registrations#destroy
                                         POST   /users(.:format)                                                                                  users/registrations#create
                                    user GET    /user/:id(.:format)                                                                               dashboard#show
```

can someone explain me why it happens?

I expected as it seem in `rails routes` to be using `user_registration_path`